# Is there a tool online to do the A* algorithm for a user-inputted tree?

Tags: algorithms

I'm learning about various path algorithms at the minute.

I found [this](https://raphsilva.github.io/utilities/minimax_simulator/#) tool really useful for learning alpha-beta pruning. I'm able to build a tree from a past exam paper, try to prune it myself, and then use this tool to get what the solution should have been, and compare to mine.

This approach really worked for me, and I'm looking for a similar online tool for A* (the A-Star algorithm). I was able to find [this](https://www.101computing.net/a-star-search-algorithm/) which will definitely be useful, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a tool similar, but where I can input a tree and g/h values for the nodes, and it will show you the process of doing the A* algorithm for that tree?

I couldn't see any myself, so thought I would just ask the community.

Comment: Welcome Slowat_Kela!  Are you looking for a web-app, or software to run locally?  If the later, which operating system(s)?  Also, I'm guessing you are looking for recommendations for gratis (free of charge) solutions, but would you consider ones where you have to pay?  If you update your question with these details, it will help us help you.  Thanks, and again, welcome!